# What is the voltage in this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, voltage

Attached is an image of circuit diagram for which I was asked to calculate the voltage for. However, because of the lack of information provided I belive this is impossible. Am I correct?[image: Circuit]

Comment: You are right, you can still calculate voltage ratios, are you sure the supply voltage isn't given?

Comment: @Vishwaas No, the voltage isn't given. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, if both batteries have equal potential difference, then the net potential difference will zero between any two points of circuit, so the answer is zero.

However, this is a guess, since no information is given and both batteries seem identical in the figure.

Comment: Hi KavanPrabtani! Please do not use unexplained abbreviations like 'pd' or corruptions of words like 'bcoz', but write proper, full sentences. Also, a *single* ',' or '.' is enough, punctuation is never repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Kavan's answer, I'd say that since the two ends of the cell are facing each other (as in they cancel out) that the dots could also be interpreted to do the same. Usually dots correspond to a series that follows the same pattern given by the first term (in this case the cells that cancel out). So I'd say 0 is your best shot. If the cells aren't equal in voltage, I don't think it can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is viewed correctly the batteries are not connected to each other, therefore it is an open circuit.
Or if it is connected the batteries are facing each other and the values are not mentioned and so let us assume they are equal.

Then the net voltage is zero which is the same as no voltage so V across the 4 ohm resistance is zero.